# Site not working properly in QtDemo Browser

Tags: qt

When I open the website [WellsFargo](http://www.wellsfargo.com) in QtDemo Browser 5.3 or 5.5 and click on the menus Personal/Commercial/Small Business, the sub menus are displayed. But when I click these sub menus, nothing happens. Their menu list is not displayed.

Is is something related to the `jquery.js` or `global.js` used in the html page?

Knowing what the issue could be would help me a lot.

Regards

Comment: You're using a rather old webkit in that demo, try the newer qml-based demos that use chromium.

Comment: Qt Demo Browser 5.3 uses qtwebkit, which is being used in my project also. I have checked it in Qt5.5 demo browser also. Is there any way or strong reason through which I can prove that why this is not working in Qt Demo Browser. Or any patch which can be given?

Comment: A *lot* of Qt demos use approaches that are outdated. The Qt Demo Browser is not necessarily the best example of what you should be doing. You're simply using a webkit too old to deal with the Wells Fargo website. That's *all*. There's no reason to use it, especially that the webkit module is deprecated and not supported anymore. Use Qt WebEngine instead!

Comment: Thanks. But, my project is browser based which uses Qt5.3 , therefore, qtwebkit is used. That's why we compare our functionality through QtDemo Browser 5.3. So, there must be some property which is not supported in this old webkit version.

Comment: Well, yeah, if you insist on using outdated webkit, expect stuff to be broken or expect to spend the time fixing it yourself. I presume that you have an out-of-support Qt commercial license, and that's why you're stuck with 5.3. If so, then is your time spent maintaining webkit to work with random websites like WellsFargo worth it, compared to paying for up to date Qt? Proceed according to what makes financial sense...

Comment: Alas, your question is really off-topic. For it to be on-topic, you'd have to isolate the failing markup/script from the bank's site and create a test case. You'll have to do it *anyway* if you insist on supporting the old version of webkit that you're using.

Comment: This problem is occuring because it is treating QtDemoBrowser as touch device.They have written a code due to which menu is not displayed for devices that support touch. And, I am working on thisold webkit because this is my project requirement.